# Unpacking rar on iPhone

Tags: iphone, file, iterable-unpacking

I created little download application with music player and now I want it to unpack archives, because quite often mp3s are packed in archive and you can play them before you unpack the archive.
I found solution for .zip files on iPhone here on stackoverflow, but I'm wondering if there's a way to unpack .rar files, or other than .zip formats.. Many times, I red about creating own utility to do this, but I don't know whether I am able to create it or not. 
Could you please tell me if there's any solution for unpacking .rar(or simply other than .zip) archives on iPhone?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[UnRar](http://www.tucows.com/preview/8753) has source code included, so if all fails, you could have a look if there is a port for the iPhone or try to do this yourself. For Symbian Phones, there seems to be [FreeUnRar](http://www.symbian-freeware.com/download-freeunrar.html).